# Coredata relationships how make ordered collection or added in particular index in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relational-database

I am working with core-data relationships add the student in profile entities.

Profile and Student entities are multiple relationship with each others.

Profile entities for create students, it successfully created.

I want to add or append some information that profile entities through student entities its also added.
**(Its Like: Profile entities have a array of dictionary of student entities )**

But when in display in UItableview added info of student it display in unordered.

I want to display the added student should be display in last or first.

Coredata is unordered collection of set. how to make it order.

Also selected ordered Arrangement. its shows error students not be ordered.

How can achieve this. Help me

[image]

Here my code:

```
func create(record: ProfileModel) {
        let cdProfile = CDProfile(context: PersistentStorage.shared.context)
        cdProfile.emailID = record.emailID
        cdProfile.gender = record.gender
        cdProfile.getDate = record.getDate
        cdProfile.id = record.id
        if(record.toStudent != nil && record.toStudent?.count != 0){
            var studentSet = Set<CDStudent>()
            record.toStudent?.forEach({ (student) in
                
                let cdStudent = CDStudent(context: PersistentStorage.shared.context)
                cdStudent.activity = student.activity
                cdStudent.currentPage = Int16(student.currentPage ?? 0)
                cdStudent.getPercentage = student.getPercentage

                studentSet.insert(cdStudent)
            })
            
            cdProfile.toStudent = studentSet
            
        }
        PersistentStorage.shared.saveContext()
    }


@IBAction func saveBtnClick(_ sender: Any) {

    let studentArr = StudentModel(_activity: "S-\(self.sectionString)", _studentComments: self.infotextView.text, _getPercentage: "-", _result: String(self.audioValueKey.count), _sectionID: self.sectionString, _sessionDate: self.convertedDate, _timeSpend: self.timeSpendStr, _currentPage: self.allPageNumber, _selectedValue: self.audioValueKey)
     
     if let getStudentData = userProfileArr![indexNumber].toStudent?.count{
         self.personArrCount = getStudentData
         let getArr = userProfileArr![indexNumber].toStudent!
        
        if getArr.count == 0{
            
        }else{
            for j in 0..<getArr.count{
                self.student.append(getArr[j])
               // self.student.insert(getArr[j], at: 0)
            }
            self.student.append(studentArr)
        }
     }else{
         self.personArrCount = 0
        self.student.append(studentArr)
        print("student-empty",student)
     }


let getProfileData = userProfileArr![indexNumber]

let updatePerson = ProfileModel(_id: selectedUserIndex!.id, _profileComments: getProfileData.profileComments!, _emailID: getProfileData.emailID!, _gender: getProfileData.gender!, _profileImage: getProfileData.profileImage!, _getDate: "NO", _studentDOB: getProfileData.studentDOB!, _studentName: getProfileData.studentName!, _toStudent: student)

print("student",self.student)

if(dataManager.update(record: updatePerson))
{
   print("Update added")
}else{
    print("Not-- added")
}
```

}

How can i fix this issue help me... Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

first of all Core data only provides sorting on parent table only

if you wanna sort data in a subtable you can do as below

1. First you need to add a field named student_id(int16) in student table
2. Then you need to assign value as count + 1

> As core data does not provide autoincrement field need to manage manually.

3. Follow the below code to sort data as last to first

   ```
   // assume you have fetched profile in stud_profile var 
           if let student_list = stud_profile.toStudent as? Set<CDStudent> {
             let arrStudents = Array(student_list).sorted(by: {$0.student_id > $1.student_id})
           }
   ```

4.You can use arrStudents as it will return sorted [CDStudent]